# Tidy some json with multiple lists

Tags: r, purrr

I have one pull of data from an API. The data has multiple nested lists. What is an efficient way to clean up this data?

For reference I was trying to follow this post on [parsing json with purrr](https://rensa.co/writing/drilling-into-non-rectangular-data-with-purrr/), but it seems that my data has more nested lists so I had some difficulty with it.

```
> jsonRespParsed %>% dput()
list(list(GameId = 14491L, Season = 2019L, SeasonType = 3L, Day = "2019-04-14T00:00:00", 
    DateTime = "2019-04-14T12:00:00", Status = "Final", AwayTeamId = 11L, 
    HomeTeamId = 14L, AwayTeamName = "NYI", HomeTeamName = "PIT", 
    GlobalGameId = 30014491L, GlobalAwayTeamId = 30000011L, GlobalHomeTeamId = 30000014L, 
    HomeTeamScore = 1L, AwayTeamScore = 4L, TotalScore = 5L, 
    PregameOdds = list(), LiveOdds = list(list(GameOddId = 384105L, 
        Sportsbook = NULL, GameId = 14491L, Created = "2019-04-14T14:26:30", 
        Updated = "2019-04-14T14:54:50", HomeMoneyLine = 300L, 
        AwayMoneyLine = -397L, HomePointSpread = 1.7, AwayPointSpread = -1.7, 
        HomePointSpreadPayout = -255L, AwayPointSpreadPayout = 207L, 
        OverUnder = 5.1, OverPayout = -187L, UnderPayout = 157L))), 
    list(GameId = 14492L, Season = 2019L, SeasonType = 3L, Day = "2019-04-14T00:00:00", 
        DateTime = "2019-04-14T19:00:00", Status = "Final", AwayTeamId = 6L, 
        HomeTeamId = 16L, AwayTeamName = "TB", HomeTeamName = "CBJ", 
        GlobalGameId = 30014492L, GlobalAwayTeamId = 30000006L, 
        GlobalHomeTeamId = 30000016L, HomeTeamScore = 3L, AwayTeamScore = 1L, 
        TotalScore = 4L, PregameOdds = list(), LiveOdds = list(
            list(GameOddId = 385269L, Sportsbook = NULL, GameId = 14492L, 
                Created = "2019-04-14T21:16:43", Updated = "2019-04-14T21:44:55", 
                HomeMoneyLine = -475L, AwayMoneyLine = 327L, 
                HomePointSpread = -1.7, AwayPointSpread = 1.7, 
                HomePointSpreadPayout = 202L, AwayPointSpreadPayout = -254L, 
                OverUnder = 5.1, OverPayout = -174L, UnderPayout = 146L))), 
    list(GameId = 14493L, Season = 2019L, SeasonType = 3L, Day = "2019-04-14T00:00:00", 
        DateTime = "2019-04-14T19:30:00", Status = "Final", AwayTeamId = 22L, 
        HomeTeamId = 20L, AwayTeamName = "WPG", HomeTeamName = "STL", 
        GlobalGameId = 30014493L, GlobalAwayTeamId = 30000022L, 
        GlobalHomeTeamId = 30000020L, HomeTeamScore = 3L, AwayTeamScore = 6L, 
        TotalScore = 10L, PregameOdds = list(), LiveOdds = list(
            list(GameOddId = 385329L, Sportsbook = NULL, GameId = 14493L, 
                Created = "2019-04-14T21:49:05", Updated = "2019-04-14T22:19:58", 
                HomeMoneyLine = NULL, AwayMoneyLine = NULL, HomePointSpread = 3.9, 
                AwayPointSpread = -3.9, HomePointSpreadPayout = -272L, 
                AwayPointSpreadPayout = 216L, OverUnder = 8.5, 
                OverPayout = -226L, UnderPayout = 184L))), list(
        GameId = 14494L, Season = 2019L, SeasonType = 3L, Day = "2019-04-14T00:00:00", 
        DateTime = "2019-04-14T22:00:00", Status = "Final", AwayTeamId = 27L, 
        HomeTeamId = 35L, AwayTeamName = "SJ", HomeTeamName = "VEG", 
        GlobalGameId = 30014494L, GlobalAwayTeamId = 30000027L, 
        GlobalHomeTeamId = 30000035L, HomeTeamScore = 6L, AwayTeamScore = 3L, 
        TotalScore = 10L, PregameOdds = list(), LiveOdds = list(
            list(GameOddId = 385764L, Sportsbook = NULL, GameId = 14494L, 
                Created = "2019-04-15T00:24:40", Updated = "2019-04-15T00:54:53", 
                HomeMoneyLine = NULL, AwayMoneyLine = NULL, HomePointSpread = -2.8, 
                AwayPointSpread = 2.8, HomePointSpreadPayout = 129L, 
                AwayPointSpreadPayout = -149L, OverUnder = 10.7, 
                OverPayout = 126L, UnderPayout = -145L))))
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to clean up here? What's the desired output?

Comment: The desired output is a dataframe. Each GameId is a new row

Comment: And what should that data frame look like? Data dramas aren’t really meant to hold nested data.

Comment: I see. Let me edit and provide more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your sample data looks pretty straight forward.  Each object in the primary list only contains a single unique list.  You could unlist each object, convert to a data.frame and then bind them all together.

Assuming your data is named "jsonRespParsed":

```
games<-lapply(jsonRespParsed, function(game){data.frame(t(unlist(game)))})

library(dplyr)
answer<-bind_rows(games)


answer
#GameId Season SeasonType                 Day            DateTime Status AwayTeamId HomeTeamId AwayTeamName
#1  14491   2019          3 2019-04-14T00:00:00 2019-04-14T12:00:00  Final         11         14          NYI
#2  14492   2019          3 2019-04-14T00:00:00 2019-04-14T19:00:00  Final          6         16           TB
#3  14493   2019          3 2019-04-14T00:00:00 2019-04-14T19:30:00  Final         22         20          WPG
#4  14494   2019          3 2019-04-14T00:00:00 2019-04-14T22:00:00  Final         27         35           SJ
```

Comment: The `t()` transpose is a simple, but effective step. Thanks for the help!